# Parse.com ~ PFObject to Array Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parse-platform

I have setup a Parse.com backend. In my iOS application I have connection with this backend and am able to retrieve the objects stored.

I want each specific object to be stored in an array. 
Let's say the objects where my Key:value is for example: Category = Coffeebars

For now I have written the following code:

```
let queryToGetBuildings = PFQuery(className: "Building")

queryToGetBuildings.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

if error == nil {
    for object in objects!{
         print("this is an object")
         print(object)
    }
 } else {
    print("something went wrong")
 }
```

Which returns each of my objects separate:

```
"this is an object"
<Building: 0x7f, objectId: yh, localId: (null)> {
    BottomText = "Opened from";
    BottomTextExtra = "05:00 until 22:00";
    Category = Coffeebars;
    MiddleText = "Suggestion:";
    MiddleTextExtra = "Apple and cinnamon";
    TimeToDestination = 5;
    TopText = Starbucks;
}

"this is an object"
<Building: 0xr, objectId: Xj, localId: (null)> {
    BottomText = "Fee per person (not for babies):";
    BottomTextExtra = "0.20";
    Category = Toilets;
    MiddleText = "Men - Women - Babies";
    MiddleTextExtra = " ";
    TimeToDestination = 5;
    TopText = "Bathroom 2 terminal A";
 }

"this is an object"
<Building: 0pr, objectId: 2q, localId: (null)> {
    BottomText = "Fee per person (not for babies):";
    BottomTextExtra = "0.20";
    Category = Toilets;
    MiddleText = "Men - Women";
    MiddleTextExtra = " ";
    TimeToDestination = 8;
    TopText = "Bathroom 3 terminal A";
}
```

My main question now is how can I print out (and add to a specific Array) all information for an object with Key:Value = Category:Toilets?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know that Parse.com is going to be shutdown?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you well, you are asking how to display fetched data.

First you should declare an array to hold fetched data:

```
var someData = [PFObject]()
```

inside your closure add this `self.someData.append(object)`, now your code should look like this:

```
let queryToGetBuildings = PFQuery(className: "Building")

queryToGetBuildings.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

if error == nil {
    for object in objects!{
         print("this is an object")
         print(object)

         // Add this line
         self.someData.append(object)
    }
 } else {
    print("something went wrong")
 }
```

After you have fetched data it's time to display:

```
// if you are using tableView to display 
let thisData = someData[indexPath.row] 

let bottomText = thisData["columnName"] as? String
let bottomTextExtra = thisData["columnName"] as? String
let category = thisData["columnName"] as? SomeType
let middleText = thisData["columnName"] as? String
let middleTextExtra = thisData["columnName"] as? String
let timeToDestination = thisData["columnName"] as? NSNumber
let topText = thisData["columnName"] as? String
```